# At some point it's pointless to buy very expensive jeans because the quality can only be so high: term for this?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary

There is a term for something being very expensive in a pointless or vain way since the quality can only reach a certain point so you're just paying for a reason besides that.

Comment: Something like https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51357 perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure 'diminishing returns' works here, as even in the region of diminishing returns there is increased benefit (albeit at nonsensical extra cost etc).

Comment: No, that may be a reason why they do it but there is a term for the crossing that quality ≠ price threshold.

Comment: << An 'appeal to wealth' ('argumentum ad crumenam') occurs when more money involved 'means' something is truer or better, exploiting the impression that money flows from intelligence or work. answered Dec 22, 2015 at 21:27 O.. >> // <<  'Veblen goods' are types of luxury goods, such as expensive wines, jewelry, fashion-designer handbags, and luxury cars, which are in demand because of the high prices asked for them.  user662852 >>

Answer (score 0):

Some words which directly come to my mind regarding material being expensive rather than utilitarian as a result of usually low supply and high demand but being inherently worthless are:

***Trend***

***Fad***

***Vogue***